# Set the background of elastic scroll backdrop in Chrome on OSX?

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome

I have a two column layout with a dark sidebar and a light main column background.

Chrome OSX (and other browsers on OSX) apply an elastic effect when the user scrolls above the top of the page, but the background of the overflow region is white.

[image]

[image]

Short of re-implementing elastic scroll, is there anything I can do to get both the sidebar and main column backgrounds to bleed off the edge during elastic scroll?

I've tried adding a `linear-gradient` background to the `html` and `body` tags, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think the elastic overflow color is based on either the `html` or `body` `background-color`. Have you tried setting those? Or are you looking to do it only in some areas? If the later, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like the background to match the backgrounds of my columns. That's why I thought maybe a `linear-gradient` background would work.